# codeigniter icones menu dissapear in subpages

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

i have a folder "coomon" where i have the different menus
In the view i have folder for each page and inside 3 pages (index, edit and new)
The page index i can see menu with icones, but when i click to go to create something (and go to page new) the menu still showing but he cant find the icones

navbar:

```
<div class="sidenav">
<img src="../assets/img/logo.svg" class="logo" /><br>
<div class="new">
  <a class="nav-link teste" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/dashboardadmin"><img src="../assets/img/speedometer.png" class="icone" />Dashboard</a>
  <a class="nav-link teste" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/users"><img src="../assets/img/user.png" class="icone" />Users</a>
  <a class="nav-link teste" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/eventos"><img src="../assets/img/event.png" class="icone" />Events</a>
  <a class="nav-link teste" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/news"><img src="../assets/img/news.png" class="icone" />News</a>
  <a class="nav-link teste" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/suporte"> <img src="../assets/img/support.png" class="icone" />Suporte</a>
  <a class="nav-link teste" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/profile"><img src="../assets/img/settings.png" class="icone" />Profile</a>
  <a class="nav-link teste" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/auth/logout"><img src="../assets/img/logout.png" class="icone" />Logout</a>
</div>
```

page new/index/edit

```
<div class="navigation-side">
        <?php
        if ($_SESSION['admin'] == "1")
            $this->load->view('common/navBaradmin');
        else if ($_SESSION['admin'] == "2")
            $this->load->view('common/navBarmanager');
        else
            $this->load->view('common/navBaruser');
        ?>
    </div>
```

Struture:
backoffice:
-application (where i have folder controllers, model, view(where i have folder common, events, etc.))
-Assets(inside i have bootstrap, css, img(is here where i have the images i want), jquery, js)

Comment: depending on your directory structure, I'd use a relative path like `"/assets/img/speedometer.png"`. Then you don't have to worry anymore how deep down in the subfolders is your view. `assets`folder should be in the same directory level as `application`

Comment: if i remove both dots, i cant find in any page
The page http://localhost/backoffice/index.php/events it shows icones, but entering the page http://localhost/backoffice/index.php/events/newevent only show the text from menu

Comment: I wrote *depending on your directory structure*: please edit your question with your directory structure, where is assets folder located, we can only guess, right now. `../`means up one directory, so it will nor work from a sub-directory, as you'd need `../../`.

Comment: i add the structure

Comment: `"/assets/img/speedometer.png"` should work, make sure it is not `"assets/img/speedometer.png"`. anyway check your browser console to see what the generated html is.

Comment: Both ways, same error
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: last try, `"<?=base_url()?>assets/img/speedometer.png"`. And check in your browser Elements Tab (inspect element) how the generated html looks like (F12)

Comment: i did it, but i had to duplicate the navbar with a differente name and add "../" to all images